# tool for displaying more than 4 DIMM SPD entries in Windows

Tags: windows, memory, memory-timings

CPU-Z is able to read SPD manufacturer-recommended DRAM timing values from the onboard ROM in every DIMM.  However, it only displays 4 at once, and there doesn't appear to be any way to scroll and view the others.

[image]

Please recommend a tool for viewing the other SPD table entries (either a new tool, or a way to scroll through the ones in CPU-Z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPU-Z can write a report out to a text file, see the About tab.

```
Memory SPD
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

DIMM #              1
    SMBus address       0x50
    Memory type     DDR3
    Module format       UDIMM
    Manufacturer (ID)   Micron Technology (2C00000000000000)
    Size            4096 MBytes
    Max bandwidth       PC3-12800 (800 MHz)
    Part number     18KSF51272AZ-1G6M1
    Serial number       DE8D1A44
    Manufacturing date  Week 14/Year 12
    Number of banks     8
    Nominal Voltage     1.28 Volts
    EPP         no
    XMP         no
JEDEC timings table     CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC @ frequency
    JEDEC #1        5.0-5-5-14-19 @ 380 MHz
    JEDEC #2        6.0-6-6-16-22 @ 457 MHz
    JEDEC #3        7.0-7-7-19-26 @ 533 MHz
    JEDEC #4        8.0-8-8-22-30 @ 609 MHz
    JEDEC #5        9.0-9-9-24-33 @ 685 MHz
    JEDEC #6        10.0-10-10-27-37 @ 761 MHz
    JEDEC #7        11.0-11-11-30-41 @ 838 MHz
```

Unfortunately, it appears that all the JEDEC entries are wrong (this memory is sold as 1.35V, CL=9 @ DDR3-1600, and works fine with those settings when manually configured in the BIOS).